# Paizaラーニングで解答をコピペして提出してもエラーになる

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Paizaラーニングというオンライン教材でphp言語の勉強をしておりそこで出題された演習問題が分からなかったので、解答をコピペして動作確認を行いました。そこで、実行すると解答と同じプログラムを入力したのですが「出力結果が間違っています」となり、Errorになってしまいます。

実行環境は、PaizaCloud(クラウドIDE)を教材の中で使用する形になっており実行環境の設定などは基本行えません。
問題や解答などは規約に引っ掛かりそうなので載せる事はできなそうです。（問題の概要は、特定の項目を表示させると言うものです。）
エラー原因を解読しているのですが、中々意味を理解できません。
どなたか力をお貸しいただけないでしょうか。

もし不明な点や不足している情報が何かあれば、追記いたしますので教えてください。
また、質問の仕方などのアドバイスのみでもありがたいです。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

私の行った手順は以下です。
(1)演習問題が分からず解答をコピペ
(2)解答と同じものを入力したがエラーになる
(3)表示されたエラー内容の解読をするも、何がエラーの原因なのかわからない。

以下がエラー内容です。

```
実行結果
コード判定詳細
テスト番号   
ジャッジ結果  
実行時間
1
Error （出力結果が間違っています）    
6.16 秒
 特定職業のプレイヤーインデックスを表示する
 expected: truthy value got: false

id: "./spec/test_spec.rb[1:1]"
description: 特定職業のプレイヤーインデックスを表示する
full_description: 特定職業のプレイヤーインデックスを表示する
status: failed
file_path: "./spec/test_spec.rb"
line_number: 5
run_time: 0.598872409
pending_message:
exception:
class: RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError
message: |-
expected: truthy value
got: false

    backtrace:
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-support-3.9.2/lib/rspec/support.rb:97:in
`block in <module:Support>'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-support-3.9.2/lib/rspec/support.rb:106:in
`notify_failure'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.9.0/lib/rspec/expectations/fail_with.rb:35:in
`fail_with'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.9.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:40:in
`handle_failure'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.9.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:50:in
`block in handle_matcher'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.9.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:27:in
`with_matcher'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.9.0/lib/rspec/expectations/handler.rb:48:in
`handle_matcher'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-expectations-3.9.0/lib/rspec/expectations/expectation_target.rb:65:in
`to'"
- "/home/ubuntu/test/spec/test_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in '"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:257:in
`instance_exec'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:257:in
`block in run'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:503:in
`block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:460:in
`block in with_around_example_hooks'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:472:in
`block in run'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:612:in
`block in run_around_example_hooks_for'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:345:in
`call'"
- "/home/ubuntu/test/spec/spec_helper.rb:143:in `block (2 levels) in '"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:450:in
`instance_exec'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:450:in
`instance_exec'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:381:in
`execute_with'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:614:in
`block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:345:in
`call'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:615:in
`run_around_example_hooks_for'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:472:in
`run'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:460:in
`with_around_example_hooks'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:503:in
`with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:254:in
`run'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:633:in
`block in run_examples'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:629:in
`map'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:629:in
`run_examples'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:595:in
`run'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in
`block (3 levels) in run_specs'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in
`map'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:121:in
`block (2 levels) in run_specs'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2031:in
`with_suite_hooks'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:116:in
`block in run_specs'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:74:in
`report'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:115:in
`run_specs'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:89:in
`run'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in
`run'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in
`invoke'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.9.1/exe/rspec:4:in
`'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/rspec:23:in `load'"
- "/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/rspec:23:in `

'"

テストケース通過率: 0 ％
close
```

原因を確かめるため、以下のような事を行ってみましたが
問題の解決には至りませんでした。

(1) 問題のコピー&ペースト
→手入力で入力してみるが結果は同じ

(2) gemが関係しているのかと思い調べてみる
→オンライン実行環境はそのときの演習問題に対して設定が変更されるので
今の問題と関係ない。

(3) 1日かけても分からなかったので演習問題出題先企業に問い合わせる
→混み合っているようなので返信なし。そもそもこのような問い合わせを受け付けていないのかもしれません。

私の環境は以下の通りです。
【Mac,PaizaCloud(クラウドIDE)】

何かこの問題に対しての解決策や、アドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: php言語の勉強をしていらっしゃるとの事ですが、backtraceにはrubyのファイル(拡張子が .rbのファイル）が列挙されています。
rubyのプログラミングも勉強されていますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。rubyの勉強はしておりません。

Comment: rubyはわからないのですが、言語選択でrubyを選択しているか、Paizaラーニングのジャッジシステムがrubyで書かれていて、それ自体が落ちているように見えます。前者でないことを確認したらPaizaのサポートに連絡してみてはどうでしょう

Comment: 問題 (コード) を載せるのが難しいのであれば、[どの講座](https://paiza.jp/works/search_courses/2207) を受けているかの情報があると多少は回答のヒントになるかもしれません。 / いずれにせよ、まずは Paiza からの回答を待つべきだと思いますし、十分なサポートが受けられないなら利用自体を再検討した方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: cubickさん、行っている講座は『PHP-Web入門編4:Eloquentでデータベースを操作しよう』のナンバー9のチャプターです。とりあえず回答を待ちます！ありがとうございます！

Comment: v..snowさん、演習問題では言語選択をしていないのでやはりサポートの連絡を待つことにします。

Comment: 問い合わせの返信が来ました！paiza側の採点時の不具合だったようです。再度同じ流れで動作確認した所採点が問題なく行われエラーになりませんでした。オンライン学習サイトでの不具合は予想外でした。学習サイトでエラーなどがおこり一定時間調べても原因が分からない場合はサイト側に問い合わせる事が大事だと分かり良かったです！皆様ご協力くださりありがとうございました。